A man who can not see his own paint
The movie is about a man who is still young and he can't see his painted photo, otherwise he will be old, and in the end of the movie he will see his photo and he will die.

Could be any movie using the Dorian Gray character. Can you give more details?

yes it's Dorian Gray thanks

May be you are talking about The League of extraordinary Gentlemen having the Dorian Gray Character. A wiki link on the film is here. The character you are talking about is Dorian Gray (played by Stuart Townsend). He remains youthful by not looking into his own portrait. As a result the portrait ages instead of him and he becomes immortal. But at the end of the movie Mina confronts Dorian and kills him by exposing his portrait to him.

What makes you believe it's this movie and not some other movie based on/inspired by the novel?

@CodesInChaos, Previously I was unaware of the novel, but I must say I am lucky, it is the movie the asker was searching for! :)

Check Dorian Gray (film). It's the same story and based on the original novel by Oscar Wilde, under the title "The Picture of Dorian Gray".
